# referencing array elements returned by a function

Tags: php

Is there a ways to shorten this code, to get rid of the helper variable `$arr`:

```
$arr = myfunc('param');
$b = $arr[0]['elem']['field'];
```

Something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
$b = myfunc('param')[0]['elem']['field'];
```

Comment: You can do this since php 5.4

Comment: read PHP docs before asking > http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89
Its possible since 5.4 version

Comment: Docs says : "As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable."